# Allow customers to upload files directly to local ftp server on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp, upload

I'm currently working on a website that is built using Wordpress and would like to have the functionality to have clients upload files on the website for printing and have those files go directly to a local FTP server.

How can I accomplish this? There are very few plugins that allow uploading to an FTP server and the plugins that do exist seem just allow the user to upload the file which goes to the media library on the host server and then copy the file to the FTP server. I'd like to be able to just have the user upload the file and it goes directly to our local FTP server. Is that possible and is there a plugin out there that can achieve that? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example without file validation. You should always validate uploaded file before actually saving it or using it anywhere. Also this example shows how to upload single file and then transfer it using FTP. For multiple file handling, please modify this code.

Say you have uploaded the file and now have a file handle as $file. And you also have credentials for FTP server.

```
// best to keep this in a separate file as a constant or variable
$ftp_host = 'ftp.example.com';
$ftp_user = 'ftp_username';
$ftp_password = 'ftp_password';
// Try to get the filename from the $file, if you want to keep
// same filename. usually it is $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
$remote_filename = 'uploaded_file_name.txt';

// now we try to connect to ftp server
$ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
$login = ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

if(!$ftp || $!login) {
    // you can add logics here
    echo 'FTP login failed';
}

if(ftp_fput($ftp, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "File successfully uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Failed to upload file";
}

ftp_close($ftp);
```

Comment: Is there a wordpress plugin that creates a form and allows a file to be uploaded using this functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any plugin like this.